# defining month first dateformat in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can i define month first dateformat in pandas?

for date first format I define like using **dayfirst** attribute;

```
 dateCols = ['Document Date']
 data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(delivery_path, f), parse_dates=dateCols,
                                 dayfirst=True, sheet_name='Refined', skiprows=1)
```

There is no **monthfirst** attribute. How should I define that when reading the file? And also what is the default dateformat panda uses when reading date columns?

eg: **October 1st =10/01/2019**

Comment: Can you show us what is your date column and its content?

Comment: @Tserenjamts October 1st =10/01/2019

Comment: `data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', parse_dates=['Document Date'])` should properly parse dates in the form `10/01/2019`.  The result in the `Document Date` column will be `2019-10-01`, which is year-month-day.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yes it works without definig any parameter. So, this shows that pandas default dateformat is month/date/year?

Comment: It‘s safe to say the default datetime format is y-m-d.  If directed, pandas will attempt to infer the date from a variety of formats.  However, based on the dayfirst attribute, the parser needs guidance.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney gret thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your date column is like this `October 1st=10/01/2019` or this `10/01/2019` if your column is `October 1st=10/01/2019`

```
import pandas as pd
def clean(date_column):
    date = str(date_column).split('=')
    return date[1]

data[dateCols] = pd.to_datetime(data[dateCols].apply(clean),format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

if `10/01/2019`

`data[dateCols] = pd.to_datetime(data[dateCols],format='%m/%d/%Y')`

for the format you can learn more about from here http://strftime.org/

Comment: it is 10/01/2019 (Imentioned like october 1st will be represented as 10/01/2019)

Comment: `data[dateCols] = pd.to_datetime(data[dateCols],format='%m/%d/%Y')` this is what you re searching for